Можно ли так сказать: Буква читается и, соответственно, звучит
Можно ли так сказать: "Буква читается и, соответственно, звучит точь-в точь как какая-нибудь другая буква"?
Например: Буква О в этом слове читается и, соответственно, звучит точь-в точь как А.
Глагол "читается" уместен, если мы говорим о букве. Смущает глагол "звучит". Но ведь если читается, то, соответственно, и звучит...

"В этом слоге буква О произносится(читается) как звук А." Просто отдельно нужно рассказать, что есть звуки, а есть буквы: буквы могут произноситься в слогах не так, как звуки отдельных букв, и звуков больше, чем оригинальных звучаний букв в Алфавите. Например в Алфавите все согласные буквы произносятся твёрдо, а в словах и слогах могут звучать мягко. Ну а буквы Ь и Ъ звучания отдельного, как буквы, не имеют.

Лучше: произносится (терминология).  Звучит  музыка, гитара, песня, голос https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=звучать&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42

И все-таки, если отойти от клише, можно сказать: читается и, соответственно, звучит?

Сказать можно, но будет непонятно и криво. И там не только в этом слове проблема, но и в словах "звучит", "буква", "слово"(правильно "слог")...

Буквы русского алфавита соответствуют звукам. Пара буква-звук нераздельна. «...Если буква читается, то, соответственно, и звучит»? Если она читается, то соответственно написанному и произносится.
